# How to Set Micronaut Context Path

Tags: micronaut

How does one go about setting a context path for a micronaut microservice?  I want to do something similar to what is available in the Spring Framework where you can set the 'server.servlet.contextPath' property.  I haven't been able to find anything in the micronaut docs [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html).  I would like to set a base path for my microservice and my 'bar' controller (e.g. http://domain/foo/bar).  In Spring this would look like

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: foo
```

I am currently using micronaut 1.0.0.M4.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Micronaut's non-blocking HTTP server is based on Netty. I don't think there is a concept of a "context" in Netty – the same happens nowadays on Spring WebFlux (using Netty).

Answer (score 9):

You can set the context path in the configuration with

```
micronaut:
  server:
    context-path: /my-path
```

Documentation: [link](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.http.server.HttpServerConfiguration)

Comment: Get right indentation for k8 configmap https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/blob/dev/application.example.yml#L33

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to set a base path for my microservice and my 'bar'
>   controller (e.g. http://domain/foo/bar)

If you want `BarController` to respond when a request is sent to `/foo/bar`, one way to get there is like this...

```
@Controller("/foo/bar")
public class BarController {

    @Get("/")
    public SomeReturnType index() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Micronaut 3:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-demo
  server:
    context-path: ${ENV_CONTEXT_PATH:`/`}
```

With this config you can define the context path as env variable, otherwise default to "/" (no specific context path).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you can add a context path to a controller in the following way

`@Controller("${micronaut.context.path:}/api"`

This works for controllers, and will give you `/api` if the path is not defined. One big caveat with this, is that your swagger doc will no longer function correctly as the compile time generation does not take into account the property and will resolve it as `/api`